# Javascript current date with an argument

Tags: javascript

Pretty straightforward, I have this:

```
var optionalDate;
var date = new Date(optionalDate || null);
```

What I want to do is, create a date with the optional date if available, if not, create today's date. If I pass null to the function (as it is in the example), it will create Wed Dec 31 1969, If I pass "", won't work, and if I leave blank, also won't work..

Is there any parameter that can be used to get today's date (I know the absence of parameters would work, but wouldn't be valid in the || operation) . Sorry for the simple question, but I couldn't find the answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try,

```
var date = new Date(optionalDate || Date.now());
```

`date` gives you the current date **IF** `optionalDate` is either `'', null or false`.

Comment: @nikoss I think the result is totally the same with yours or Barmars. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a ternary expression:

```
var date = optionalDate ? new Date(optionalDate) : new Date();
```

Answer (score 1):

If You pass null inside Date object it will return `Thu Jan 01 1970`
so you can't do that instead you can  check if that exists like below:

```
optionalDate?new Date(optionalDate):new Date;
```

this will return a date object from optional date if possible otherwise today's date